# similar to FizzBuzz with a twist

Tags: javascript

Write a javascript program that displays the numbers from 10 to 100. But for multiples of 4 print "Penny" instead of the number and for multiples of 6 print "Leonard". For numbers which are multiples of both 4 and 6 print "Bazzinga"

I know how to do two parts struggling to print 6 and 4;

```
function baZzinga (number) {
  for (var number = 10; number <= 101; number++) 
if(number % 4 == 0) {
console.log("penny");
}
else if (number % 6 == 0) {
 console.log("Leonard");
} else if ( not sure what goes here) {
 help help help
} else {
console.log(number");
}
```

Comment: Check the `&&` condition **first**.

Answer (score 0):

You want the and condition first. Try this

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function baZzinga (number) {
    for (var number = 10; number <= 101; number++)  {
        if (number % 4 == 0 && number % 6 == 0) {
            result.innerHTML += "Bazinga";
        } 
        else if(number % 4 == 0) {
            result.innerHTML += "penny";
        }
        else if (number % 6 == 0) {
            result.innerHTML += "Leonard";
        } 
        else {
            result.innerHTML += number;
        }
   }
}

baZzinga()
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

I changed console.log to result.innerHTML because I wanted to demonstrate it in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments on your code -- constructive criticism, I hope!  First, you don't need the `number` parameter in your `bazzinga` function.  Next, the indentation of the code you posted makes it hard to read.  Finally, you should almost always use `===` instead of `==`.  The `===` tests for strict equality, whereas `==` tries to do some type conversions first (and can therefore produce unexpected results).  See [the official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

To answer you question:  check for divisibility by 6 AND 8 first.  That way, it will override the individual cases.  I believe you want something like this:

```
function bazzinga() {
  for (var number = 10; number <= 100; number++) {
    if (number % 4 === 0 && number % 6 === 0) {
      console.log("Bazzinga");
    } else if (number % 4 === 0) {
      console.log("Penny");
    } else if (number % 6 === 0) {
      console.log("Leonard");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the format you posted:

```
  for (var number = 10; number <= 100; number++) {
    if(number % 4 === 0 && number % 6 === 0){
      console.log("bazzinga");
    } else if(number % 4 === 0) {
    console.log("penny");
    } else if (number % 6 === 0) {
     console.log("Leonard");
    } else {
    console.log(number);
   }
}
```

Or use the ternary operator to be even more succinct!

```
for (var i = 10; i <= 100; i++){
  var penny = i % 4 === 0;
  var leonard = i % 6 === 0;
  console.log(penny ? (leonard ? "bazzinga" : "penny"): leonard ? "leonard" : i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function process_num(num) {
  return num % 4 == 0 ? num % 6 == 0 ? "Bazzinga" : "Penny" : num % 6 == 0 ? "Leonard" : num;
}

for (x = 10; x <= 100; x++) { console.log( x + ': is ', process_num(x)) }
```

Nested Ternary operator for conciseness

If it passes outer ternary test it is divisible by 4:

- Enter into nested termary one to test if num is also divisible by 6 for the BaZzinga  prize!!
- If it fails the BaZzinga challenge, we know it previously passed the divisible by 4 test so print "penny"

Failing the outer ternary condition, we know it's not divisible by 4:

- Enter nested ternary two to consider if divisible by 6. If so print "Leonard".
- If not it's failed both the outer (div by 4) and inner (div by 6) so return the number unchanged.

Now that the logic is contained in the function, we can just create a for loop to iterate over the required numbers printing out the correct values.